# How to store all .vscode settings on one place, separate from workspace directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to store all .vscode settings on one place, separate from workspace directory? e.g. in home dir, is it possible at all?

.vscode is a developer specific configuration and should be ignored by VCS. Problem is that when I want to share the project specific setting among computers - I want to debug the project the same way at one PC as I would at another.

I was hoping to configure the editor to save all the workspaces' settings  on place, which could be shared among computers easily.

Comment: if you only modify User settings you never get a `settings.json` in your `.vscode` directory

Comment: Yes, but what about `.vscode/launch.json`, Code's debug configurations?